# PASSWORD_BCRYPT - Não funciona com Fopen

Tags: php

Boa Noite!

Uso a função PASSWORD_BCRYPT para criptografar minhas senhas. Quando utilizo o código abaixo:

```
    //conteudo do pass.txt é: yW9ujS
    $arquivo = fopen('/tmp/pass.txt','r+');
    $linha = fgets($arquivo);
    $senha = password_hash($linha, PASSWORD_BCRYPT, [cost => 12]);
     echo "$senha";
```

Gera um Hash conforme esperado. Salvo este Hash no banco de dados e quando tento acesso em minha aplicação com o usuário e senha (yW9ujS) ele diz que a senha está invalida.

Caso eu use o comando abaixo:

```
 //conteudo do pass.txt é: yW9ujS
        $arquivo = "yW9ujS";
        $senha = password_hash($arquivo, PASSWORD_BCRYPT, [cost => 12]);
         echo "$senha";
```

É gerado um hash e quando eu salvo este novo hash no banco, faço um teste de acesso na aplicação, e o acesso acontece.

Parece que quando uso o fopen, é acrescentado algum "Lixo" durante o processo e o PASSWORD_BCRYPT acaba encriptando tudo junto e o hash acaba mudando.

Se eu apenas mando um echo no $linha, aparece exatamente a senha que está no arquivo pass.txt

```
$linha = fgets($arquivo);
```

Alguem imagina o que pode ser?

Comment: Não era mais fácil usar `file_get_contents`?

Comment: Sim, usei esta função tambem : `$linhas = file_get_contents("/tmp/pass.txt");
$senha = password_hash($linhas, PASSWORD_BCRYPT, [cost => 12]);
echo $senha`, ele gera um Hash e eu setando este hash no banco não loga. Se eu setar uma variavel com a mesma senha e chamar a função acima, gera um novo hash, seto no banco e loga.

Comment: Ele retorna assim `$2y$12$oFYcRX2SKgg3b5rn0lNylu0WtUCo58tWNm66jmtcIKwQ8AdAQiW4y[root@ scripts]#` enquanto setando a senha de forma manual retorna assim `$2y$12$.4x5s/pWzNXjlvXLlDvNH.gkHjgH0B5Bvct2FABcTFCHGBY5EKPsW`., creio que esse retorno com root... está gerando o problema.

Comment: Caros, realmente o problema era algum lixo no processo, usei as funções `trim,  preg_replace('/s(?=s)/', '' , preg_replace('/[nrt]/', ' ' ` e funcionou.